# Returning a week number for any given date and starting from a custom date

Tags: sql, function, dateadd, datepart

well, I'm trying to create a function that return week number, but not like date part that return it for the normal year (01-jannuary - 31 december) i want to retutn it using a custom year (01 september- 31 august of the next year )
also I have some rules like:

- first of september is alwayse in week number 1.
  -sunday is the last day of the week.
- if sunday is the first day of september, then the first week ends until the next sunday.

I expect to get results using code like

```
select week_number('01/09/2019')
```

Results : 1

```
select week_number('04/09/2017')
```

Results : 2

Comment: rdbms name please

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and especially with date and timestamp functions the differences between products are substantial. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question add the code of the function you have written so far

Comment: hi,
i'm using sql-server 2012, and my main probleme is that the year start in 01 september and ends at 31 august, the first of september is always week number 1 no matter what, and the weeks start at monday . i hope i was clear enough though. thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Number of the week in the month:

```
declare @date datetime = '01/09/2017'

select (DATEPART(week,@Date)- DATEPART(week,DATEADD(m, DATEDIFF(m, 0, @Date), 0)))
```

Number of the week in the year:

```
declare @date datetime = '01/09/2017'

SELECT DATEPART(wk,@Date)
```

Comment: Thank you miguel for your help i really appreciate it. the code above return the number of weeks, while i want to return the week numbr like : 01/09/2019 is the first week and 31/08/2019 is 53 week

Comment: Hi Kevin did you try SELECT DATEPART( wk, '09/01/2019')?

Comment: yes, actually the main probleme is i have a custom year: 01/09 to 30-08 and with all the rules i mention above

Comment: Hi kevin, you have different date formats? Is that it?